# JSF SelectOneMenu show items with leading spaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i want to return dropDown box with leading spaces, so it would look like a hierarchy of some sort. But `p:slectOneMenu` trims leading spaces. Any ideas how to make widget leave spaces? Cheers.

Here is example code:

```
@ManagedBean
public class AppBean {

    private String city;
    private List<String> cities = new ArrayList<String>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        cities = new ArrayList<String>(
                Arrays.asList(
                        "USA",
                        "   New York",
                        "UK",
                        "   London",
                        "   Glasgow",
                        "Spain",
                        "   Barcelona"
                        ));

    }
```

jsf code:

```
<h:form>
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{appBean.city}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{appBean.cities}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved problem by adding css to my initial code:

```
.ui-selectonemenu-panel .ui-selectonemenu-list-item {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the spaces with `nbsp;`.

```
<h:form>
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{appBean.city}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{appBean.cities}" var="city" itemLabel="#{city.replace(' ', '&nbsp;')}" itemValue="#{city}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

Comment: if use trim() is better because in case city="   New York" result with replace is "NewYork"

Comment: @sghaier he wants to **keep** the spaces. What I posted will keep the space between New and York.

Comment: @SimonArsenault I got exception : 
`javax.servlet.ServletException: Error Parsing /ui/webapp.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 12] The entity "nbsp" was referenced, but not declared.`

fixed with `<!DOCTYPE html [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;"> ]>`

Works nice, but now after selecting any subitem e.g. New York, London, Glasgow, Barcelona. In box it appears with leading spaces.

Comment: @alex - you should set `itemLabelEscaped="true"` on the `f:selectItems` to support using HTML in the output